# Biometric Dialog

Tags: android, user-interface, android-biometric-prompt

[image: Biometric Dialog Image Link]

So, I wanted to integrate Biometeric Dialog similar to that in my android app. I was following google android docs. [Here's the Link](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth) to the documentation. But I think this is for fingerprint authentication only. How to get both icons in same dialog? if two things are registered on your phone? Are they using custom api for biometric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dialog will only Appear if you are using Android 9 or higher on a device that has face ID and both faceid and fingerprints are registered

But *NOT* on samsung devices with android 9.

this is the code needed to display it:

```
val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt.Builder(context)
.setTitle(title)
.setSubtitle(subtitleText)
.setDescription(description)
.setNegativeButton(negativeButton, executor!!, cancelListener)
.build()

 biometricPrompt.authenticate(cancellationSignal, executor, BiometricCallback)
```

Comment: ohh so this also works in case of suppose user has only registered faceid? then only face icon shows in same dialog?

Comment: yes it does, 
and this is some text to fill the answer